# How to change type of variable in runtime

Tags: go, struct, types

I would like to know if it's possible to change the type of variable in run time, for example:

```
package main

import "github.com/fatih/structs"

type T struct {
  MyField bool
}

func main() {
  fakeVariable := ""

  s := structs.New(T{})
  for _, field := range s.Fields() {
    field.Set(fakeVariable) 
  }
}
```

Since MyField is a boolean, I would like to change fakeVariable to a boolean, and the expected result would be that `MyField` is false (because empty strings are false). But the MyField type could be anything, so I would like to know how to cast it to the type of MyField. I know that I can get the field type using `field.Kind()`, and this:

```
field.Set(fakeVariable.(field.Kind())
```

Won't work.

The `fakeVariable` will be always a string, but it could hold the value "10.0", and if the type of MyField is `float`, it should cast to float, but if its string, it should only assign it. Make sense?

Any ideas if what I'm trying is possible?

Comment: something like `if field is bool then field.Set(fakeVariable != "")`?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid conditionals, something like `field.Set(fakeVariable.(field.Kind()) - a dynamic type casting.

Comment: no dynamic type casting in go, use conditionals. Btw if you want to be precise in your language then there is no "type casting" in go, only *type assertions* `someValue.(someType)` and *conversions* `someType(someValue)`.

Comment: ... and to clarify my *"no dynamic type casting in go"* comment, when you're doing type assertions, ie `v.(T)`, the `T` in that expression must be a valid go type, not a variable holding some value, not an expression that results in some value, etc. That is, you can do `v.(int)` or `v.(string)`, but you cannot do `v.(getIntType())` nor `v.(stringValue)`.

Answer (score 4):

> How to change type of variable in runtime

You cannot.

Comment: That's weird, is there a reason behind this decision? Because forcing the language users to read a giant switch statement seems much more cumbersome (for the users at least)

Comment: @celoxxx The reason is the desire to provide type safety. Many developers prefer to have type safety rather then not know what the type of a variable is.